# How can I pass a directory path, ChromeOptions, and ChromeDriverService to a new ChromeDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm creating a new ChromeDriver object, but I want to pass to it a ChromeDriverService object, a ChromeOptions object, and a path to the driver. However, looking at this [page](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/Overload_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeDriver__ctor.htm), the contructor doesn't support passing all three of those. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pass both driver path and ChromeDriverService to ChromeDriver, because ChromeDriverService already takes driver path itself.

> `CreateDefaultService(String)`     Creates a default instance of the
>   ChromeDriverService using a specified path to the ChromeDriver
>   executable.
>
> `CreateDefaultService(String, String)`     Creates a default
>   instance of the ChromeDriverService using a specified path to the
>   ChromeDriver executable with the given name.

[**Documentation**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeDriverService.htm#memberList)

Answer (score 3):

Never mind, the solution is to pass the directory path into the ChromeDriverService, like this:

```
  var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService("path goes here");
```